# How do I fix broken package libgcc-s1?

Tags: apt, package-management, do-release-upgrade

When I do sudo apt upgrade libgcc-s1, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

When I do sudo apt list --upgradable

```
Listing... Done
libgcc-s1/jammy 13.1.0-2ubuntu2~22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

apt list --upgradable -a

```
Listing... Done
libgcc-s1/jammy 13.1.0-2ubuntu2~22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04]
libgcc-s1/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 13.1.0-2ubuntu2~22.04]
libgcc-s1/jammy 12-20220319-1ubuntu1 amd64
```

sudo apt-get install -f libgcc-s1

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: The `libgcc-s1/jammy 13.1.0-2ubuntu2~22.04` package is not available in Ubuntu 22.04 system repository. It seems that you have the package from 3rd party repository. Try to remove that 3rd repository via 'Software & Updates' -> 'Other Software' tab, then refresh the package cache. Or use `Synaptic Package Manager` to force `libgcc-s1` package to version `12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04`

Comment: @MerilynNe Thank you, that was exactly what was wrong.